# How to get rid of Deprecating Warning: 'np.float' is a deprecated alias for builtin 'float'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

My file has only 1 line for troubleshooting purpose

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

How to get rid of this deprecationWarning?

How to solve it.

Answer (score 5):

Upgrade your sklearn package:

`pip3.8 install scikit-learn --upgrade --user`

Answer (score 4):

Either use `float` by itself or use `np.float64`.

Comment: Tried that and warning doesn't go away.  In fact, without even before loading dataset, warning pop ups.

Comment: Please share more of the error, your code and the package versions if the above didn't fix the depreciation warning (which is very odd, because this is how you'd normally solve the numpy issue).

Comment: using dtype=float worked for me!