# i get this error when i try to import the LinearRegression module. Note: i'm using numpy version 1.24.0 and i've tried downgrading but no result

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I get this error when I try to import the `LinearRegression` module.
Note: I'm using NumPy version 1.24.0, and I've tried downgrading but no result

[image: [Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdPl5.png)]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Use `float` instead of `numpy.float`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error as formatted text, not a link to an image. Please also include the precise versions of sklearn and numpy you're using.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's better to upgrade `sklearn`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69998557/how-to-get-rid-of-deprecating-warning-np-float-is-a-deprecated-alias-for-buil?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C47.7248 says scikit 1.0 is new enough